# cordova emulate iOS never works from command line but is fine via Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

So i don't really like using multiple IDEs, i don't like Xcode, so i build ionic apps using PHPStorm and use command line tools.

Every time i run :  **ionic cordova emulate ios**
 via command line i always get this:

```
 cordova emulate ios exited with exit code 1.
```

But when i load the xcode project after build in Xcode and run in emulator it all loads fine.

So what is it with the command line that fails?

Here is a more complete error:

```
/Volumes/Work Drive/Projects/myfolder/App/platforms/ios/build/emulator/AppName.app/Info.plist file not found.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova emulate ios --verbose exited with exit code 1.
```

It can't find Info.plist because it doesn't create the ios/build/emulator folder at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this :

```
ionic cordova emulate ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Comment: That worked, but can you explain why it works, what does that flag do that made it work?